# How do I come up with a creative timestamp conversion in an Oracle query?

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle10g, odbc, utc

Output of Describe ViewName :

```
Name               Null?    Type         
------------------ -------- ------------ 
OBJID               NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
HR_NUMBER           NOT NULL NUMBER       
UTC_HR_ENDING       NOT NULL DATE         
VALUEHR                      NUMBER       
PlantUID            NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

Here is the result set from a select on this view :

```
    OBJID HR_NUMBER VALUEHR UTC_HR_ENDING    
    944 12  955 29-MAY-17
    944 13  925 29-MAY-17
    944 14  918 29-MAY-17
    944 15  922 29-MAY-17
    944 16  925 29-MAY-17
    944 17  926 30-MAY-17
    944 18  926 30-MAY-17
```

[image]

I am just a consumer of this view and I am new to Oracle. I was given this TO_CHAR conversion which magically displays the following result.

```
SELECT
objid,
hr_number,
valuehr,
utc_hr_ending,
TO_CHAR(
    utc_hr_ending,
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
) hourendingutc

FROM
    plant.hourlydata
WHERE
        ROWNUM < 10
    AND
        objid = 12767;
```

[image]

How does `TO_CHAR(UTC_HOUR_ENDING,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') HourEndingUTC` magically add the HR_NUMBER as an offset of +7? It starts with HR_NUMBER 1 is HourEndingUTC of 2017-05-29 08:00:00.

I am using this query on an application machine where we have the ODBC driver is installed and a DSN created. My client application is expecting a 'timestamp' type `HOURENDINGUTC` instead of CHAR generated by the `TO_CHAR`. How can I format the query to use `to_timestamp` instead which the client application likes but is missing the time.

This is what I have so far (losing the time but client app likes this):

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(UTC_HR_ENDING, 'DD-mm-yy HH:MI:SS') CNV_TO_TIMESTAMP
```

[image]

`TO_DATE(UTC_HR_ENDING, 'DD-mm-yy HH:MI:SS') CNV_TO_TIMESTAMP` is also acceptable by the client app but is missing the time entirely.

Is there a creative way to use the offset of +7hours and generate a timestamp value that is timestamp instead of a char? Thanks in advance! (Our Developer is not in till next week and I have to get this working this week :( )

Comment: A `DATE` column in Oracle contains a time part. The Oracle SQL tools simply hide that time part by default (which I think is a pretty stupid thing to do). If you change the date display in SQL  Developer (somewhere hidden in the "Preferences") you will see the time _without_ the need to use `to_char()`

Comment: In what timezone are you? Incidentally GMT+7? Don't forget, the to_char only reveals the timestamp info from your datefield. It was always there, only not visible. Consider the option that the timestamp data was already faulty and just not visible.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. I didn't even need a conversion. I was thinking way too much and developer's query threw me off on a rabbit trail! Date type is confusing, I wish it were datetime. Anyway, I got this resolved with a comment. If either of you can write an answer, I will select it so someone can be enlightened in the future!!

Comment: Rather, I assume you may be in UTC -7 (perhaps in California?) - anyway, that would be the result if the "current" time (in Calif.) is 1:00 AM, the UTC time would then be 8:00 AM. Other than that, it is not clear what you are looking for. Do you need to convert the date-time from UTC back to "your" time zone (subtract seven hours)? And then morph the result into a timestamp, which adds fractional seconds (perhaps you need .000)? What do you mean by "generate value that is timestamp"?

Comment: Mathguy - I was not aware of the fact that a date type can also have time in it. Client (sql developer) was hiding it and I thought it was the behavior of date type but in wrong. For it to work with no conversion and just the date and ODBC took care of it like a champ!